# Can someone explain to me how this should be corrected, to me it makes sense but i'm a newbie

Tags: javascript

Is there anyone that is able to explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, I'm trying to make it so, when the user purchases the upgrade for 300 gold it then turns the value as true once that is done. The setInterval will activate and tick every 1000MS but for some reason my else if isn't working with it. It's always telling me "Failed is not defined".

Also it doesn't take into account that the upgrade costs of 300 gold, and will change to true regardless if the user has 300 gold or not.

```js
var gameData =                     // Player Stats
  { stonePerClick          : 0    // Upgrades 
  , stoneUpgradeCost       : 25
  , woodPerClick           : 0
  , woodUpgradeCost        : 15
  , gold                   : 0    // Resources
  , wood                   : 0
  , stone                  : 0
  , planks                 : 0
  , plankcost              : 300
  , minorsettlementApplied : false // Multipliers
  } 

const minorsettlement = {woodgen: 40 , buildcost: 250}
    function settlementUpgrade () {
      if (!gameData.minorsettlementApplied) {
        if (gameData.gold >= 300) { 
        gameData.gold -= minorsettlement.buildcost
        gameData.wood += minorsettlement.woodgen
        gameData.minorsettlementApplied = true
        document.getElementById("woodCount").innerHTML = "Wood: " + gameData.wood
        var Bought = 'Purchased Upgrade.'
        document.getElementById("accepted").innerHTML = Bought 
      }
    } else if (gameData.gold < 300) {
      var Failed = 'Not Enough Gold.'
      document.getElementById("failed").innerHTML = Failed 
  }
}


function UpgradedSettlementIncome()
  {
  gameData.wood += minorsettlement.woodgen
  document.getElementById("goldIncome").innerHTML = "Gold: " + gameData.gold 
  }

var buildingUpgraded = window.setInterval(function() 
  {
  if (gameData.minorsettlementApplied === true)
    UpgradedSettlementIncome()
  } , 1000)
```

Comment: First, you should not be naming variables in pascal and should use 'let final', 'let brought', for easy readability

Comment: try changing 'Final' to 'let final' and see if the error goes away

Comment: Why does this if have no braces?  `if (gameData.gold >= minorsettlement.buildcost)`

Comment: " } else if (gameData.gold < minorsettlement.buildcost)" has the same issue. that is why you cant use let

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode

Comment: I added the missing braces in your code, which allows you to better see how it is interpreted by a javascript engine

Comment: @MisterJojo Failed & Bought are just <p id="accepted"></p> & <p id="failed"></p>

If there is enough gold, it will say the accepted (bought) line, but with the adjustments i have made, it wont show failed.

Comment: @MisterJojo i updated it to what i have right now, i have yours saved and commented out in my VSC for future reference.

Comment: @MisterJojo still doesn't want to display the failed message if < 300 gold but will allow me to purchase and display message once > 300 gold

Comment: I think you need a semi-colon after the declaration of `Failed`. Also, though it wouldn't cause any errors, you should avoid capitalizing variables and function names. Only class names should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to do that ? ( your `else if` is wrong )

```js
const 
  minorsettlement =
    { woodgen   :  40
    , buildcost : 250 
    }
, woodCount_el    = document.getElementById('woodCount')
, accepted_el     = document.getElementById('accepted')
, failed_el       = document.getElementById('failed')
, goldIncome_el   = document.getElementById('goldIncome')
, Bought          = 'Upgraded to Minor Settlement.'
, Failed          = 'Not Enough Gold.'
  ;

function settlementUpgrade ()
  {
  if (!gameData.minorsettlementApplied) 
    {
    if (gameData.gold >= 300) 
      { 
      gameData.gold                   -= minorsettlement.buildcost
      gameData.wood                   += minorsettlement.woodgen
      gameData.minorsettlementApplied  = true
      woodCount_el.textContent         = 'Wood: ' + gameData.wood
      accepted_el.textContent          = Bought 
      }
    else // if (gameData.gold < 300) 
      {
      failed_el.innerHTML = Failed 
      }
    }
  }
function UpgradedSettlementIncome()
  {
  gameData.wood             += minorsettlement.woodgen
  goldIncome_el.textContent  = 'Gold: ' + gameData.gold 
  }

var buildingUpgraded = window.setInterval(function() 
  {
  if (gameData.minorsettlementApplied === true)
    UpgradedSettlementIncome()
  } , 1000)
```

Comment: Mhmm i get an error with that "Failed is not defined". 

The code i have is working other than the else statement not displaying the failed element, it's denying the purchase because i dont have 300 gold but it will not display the failed var.

Comment: @Yami admittedly you have an error message, but you do not say on which line it appears